# Edit opportunity navigation pane

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Is it possible to add some links in opportunity navigation pane ? I want to move process (Prospecting (Active), Pre-Quota,...) navigation to marked area.
See in picture what I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't do this.  The logic of the process flow is controlled by a workflow which you can change.  However, the display within the UI is done by the CRM platform and cannot be changed.

The area that you want to move it to is the Command Bar (it used to be called the ribbon in CRM 2011).  This can be customized by adding or removing buttons but nothing as extensive as moving entire sections of the form around.  You might be able to mimic some of the functionality of the process flow from custom buttons in the command bar.  However, I think it would be unlikely to yield much benefit for the amount of work involved.